# I am unable to display 3rd, 4th and 9th row in following table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am unable to write a query to display 3rd, 4th and 9th row in following table because it doesn't contain any integer column...please help in finding the query for the same

```
_______________________________

| **name**  | **surname** | **address**   |
-------------------------------
| John  | Sailo   | Washington|
-------------------------------
| Peter | Mary    | New York  |
-------------------------------
| Sun   | Zombia  | Sri Lanka |
------------------------------- 
| Tom   | Tam     | India     |
------------------------------- 
| Addy   | Kakar  | Nepal     |
------------------------------- 
| Pun   | Zzom    | Australia |
------------------------------- 
| Tikki | Hob     | USA       |
-------------------------------
```

Comment: What defines the order of the rows? Show a query with an `order by` clause.

Comment: What is the original query you used to get that result, and what is your table schema?

Comment: Previously i was using like....SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id=3 OR id=4 OR id=9....but in this table there is no any id column...so i am amazed that how to do so

Comment: OK, what is the actual problem you are trying to solve?  How do you know it's the 3rd, 4th, and 9th rows that you want?

Comment: Daedalus...this is another question given to me in my practical's list

Comment: Mark Reed....i want to write a query to display 3rd row...and that query should display "Sun|Zombia|Sri Lanka" as output

Comment: Records in a SQL database don't have a guaranteed default sort order, so requesting a 3/4/9 row doesn't make sense.  That's what @MarkReed is getting at when he asks why it is those records you want.

Answer (score 2):

If here is no ID or other collumn which help you to sort the data you can't acomplish the task,

however, if you don't care, you can use LIMIT to get a goal

```
SELECT * from names LIMIT 0,1;
#3rd and 4th
SELECT * from names LIMIT 2,2;
#9th
SELECT * from names LIMIT 8,1;
# all
SELECT * FROM names;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b872/5

Comment: Since there is no `order by` clause, these queries can return any row. Different implementations of SQL or different runs of the query may return different results.

Comment: i agree :) I placed a note that the question is incorrect by itself